# Set hidden value via clicking on <a> block

Tags: javascript, php, html

Could you help me with this one please?
If you click on my hosting http://www.gosu.cz and select first image from top|left then it's gonna expand on top of the page with a additional info.

1. Header
2. Description
3. link

Now I need to set hidden value for each image which is defined as:

```
<li class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/857x712" data-caption="description">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/857x712" class="img-responsive" alt="alt" />
     </a>
</li>
```

and when is selected then it's gonna show up at this div which is right below header:

```
<a href="LINK+KEYWORD">
    <div class="least-preview"></div> 
</a>
```

Any ideas how could I do that please? My poor skills in programing includes some basic of html, php but not scripting.

This is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNjzq.jpg

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: What I need is to every image carry it's own hidden value whis is gonna be used lately for search link. Long story short if that person selects a image with dog, then lets say keyword is gonna be dog and it creates search link looking for word dog. But so far when is image selected I dont know which one is that.

Answer (score 1):

So as David Arce suggested it might be done through alt value.
What I have done is using script at the start and also creating link for search queue:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function () {
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt")
        var strLink = "link&Key=" + alt;
        document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href",strLink);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks to document.ElementById... I was able to set a href value via id to generated link.

```
<a id="link"> 
        <div class="least-preview"></div> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to hide, or what you want your code to do. If you want something to be hidden or visible you can use the visibility property in the css for the element you want to hide.

```
/* Hides h2 element */
h2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Shows h2 element (default value)*/    
h2 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is the reference here...
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

**In enlightenment to what the question is,** you can have an onClick="function()" attribute to your image which will grab whichever value, id, class, etc you have in your new  which can be put into a search query by variable. All can be done through a function.

Comment: I see, sorry for inaccuracy. What I would like to archive is to have keyword describing selected image to build a link in upcoming div.

Comment: So at the point when you enter website I need to have hidden value keyword or number for each image and be able to say which image is selected after user clicks on one of them

Comment: So, what if you make a js function which when the image is clicked, it grabs the alt attribute of the image so "dog" and puts that value in a new element you create in your function which builds a search query for google, then possible puts that in a <div> or whatnot.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your suggestion. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an  tag like this inside the li tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="Image_details" value="Additional details  offf that image">
```

And then on img onclick="getDetails();"

in js:

```
function getDetails()
{
   div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Img_details").value;
}
```

//The code is conceptual, so the idea is to assign the hidden input value to the  when an image is clicked or selected

Comment: Hi there, I've honestly never really worked with js. So what I've done so far is inserting that <input> into <li>, then applied onClick for that image which is in <li> and then I've improvised with that js putting that into header, then footer, then body with added alert to see it was executed but nothing has happend. Where should I put that please and where is that value gonna be saved after I click on that <li> (img) ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function () {
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt")
        var strLink = "link&Key=" + alt;
        document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href",strLink);
    });
});
```